# Adding new feature via Python in QGIS attribute table

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, attribute-table, add-feature

I want to add a new feature with the Add Feature button in the Attribute Table using one line of PyQGIS.

[image]

I can show the attribute table via

```
iface.showAttributeTable(iface.activeLayer())
```

Is there not a method like `iface.showAttributeTable(iface.activeLayer()).addFeature` available?

EDIT: The table I'm adding features to has optional geometry. When geometry is needed directly in the table, the standard Add Feature from the Edit menu works fine: the feature is digitized in and then the attribute edit dialog comes up. But in other cases the geometry is going to be referenced from another table, so I want the attribute edit dialog to come up first, as happens when the Add feature button is selected from a showAttributeTable call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for the [QgisInterface.openFeatureForm()](https://qgis.org/api/classQgisInterface.html#a11b90f38afd09ac5e9f363933ee4a509) function where you could load it using:

```
iface.openFeatureForm(iface.activeLayer(), QgsFeature(), False)
```

Comment: That's it, thanks very much Joseph. Now my challenge is to open the specific .ui form that I have generated. But your answer gets me much further along!

Comment: @RudyStricklan - Most welcome! Glad it helped :)